# Set Session To Null Using MvcContrib TestHelper

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib-testhelper

I have an action in my controller that verify if my Session has expire ( == null) and, if it's the case, redirect to my login. I would like to add a unit test for this but I can't set the Session to null or either Mock it. Any one knows how I could do that and if it's a good idea to test it?

Here's my controller action :

```
private InvestigationStep2Model _step2Model
    {
        get
        {
            if (Session == null) return null;
            if (Session["investigationStep2"] == null) Session["investigationStep2"] = new InvestigationStep2Model();
            return (InvestigationStep2Model) Session["investigationStep2"];
        }
        set { Session["investigationStep2"] = value; }
    }

public virtual ActionResult Step2()
    {
        if (_step2Model == null) return RedirectToAction(MVC.Session.Logout());
        ViewData.Model = _step2Model;
        return View();
    }
```

And my test with all my attempts to mock Session

```
[Test]
    public void Step2_RedirectToActionWhenNoSession()
    {
        _builder.InitializeController(_controller);

        Expect.Call(_controller.Session).Repeat.Any().Return(null);
        //_controller.HttpContext.Session.Abandon();//.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled); // .Session..Abandon());// .Stub(b => b.Session).Return(null);

        _mock.ReplayAll();
        var result = _controller.Step2();

        _mock.VerifyAll();
        result.AssertActionRedirect().ToAction<SessionController>(c => c.Logout());
    }
```

But nothing is working...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it :

```
[Test]
    public void Step2_RedirectToActionWhenNoSession()
    {
        _builder.InitializeController(_controller);

        _controller.HttpContext.BackToRecord();
        _controller.HttpContext.Stub(c => c.Session).Return(null);
        _controller.HttpContext.Replay();

        _mock.ReplayAll();
        var result = _controller.Step2();

        _mock.VerifyAll();
        result.AssertActionRedirect().ToAction<SessionController>(c => c.Logout());
    }
```